# as3 | How to export PNG using Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, air, png, flash-cs5

I am trying to export **transparent** PNG files using this class:
com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder;

```
var pngSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
pngSource.draw(stage);
var ba:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(pngSource);
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("test.png");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeBytes(ba);
fileStream.close();
```

All works fine - except the transparent issue...

If I could get Flash's stage color be transparent then it will work - but unfortunatly - there is no such option.

Are there any options I am missing?

Comment: Also recommend you to use better encoding library: http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make a BitmapData instance with a transparent background. You do that through the transparent argument in the [constructor](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#BitmapData%28%29) and a fill color with an alpha component(ARGB in hex):

```
var pngSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight,true,0x00FFFFFF);//'transparent white'
```

Comment: You can set the color parameter to `0`. The color will be *transparent black*, then